# Github actions / Run job after matrix is done

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

I have this situation:

```yaml
jobs:
  shake:
    name: 'NodeJS ${{ matrix.node }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        fruit: [strawberry, banana, apple]

    steps:
      - run: echo "::set-output name=action_fruit::${{ matrix.fruit }}"
```

I'd love to execute a `job` or `step` once the entire matrix is over.

- I should be able to run the job/step regardless of the failure
- I should also be able to access their output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you can achieve the desired result by using `if: always()` on your dependant job. Further info is available here: https://github.community/t/run-dependent-job-even-on-failure/115914

---

```
jobs:
  shake:
    ...
  post_shake:
    if: ${{ always() }}
    needs: [shake]
    steps:
      ...
```

Comment: To the second part of your question: accessing the outputs of a job matrix doesn't work properly, see https://github.community/t/bug-jobs-output-should-return-a-list-for-a-matrix-job/128626

Comment: No need to use interpolation for always, just use `if: always()`

Answer (score 2):

I [did that](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/aggregator-cli/blob/master/.github/workflows/build-and-deploy.yml): you must add a `needs` clause in the following job, e.g.

```yaml
jobs:
  shake:
    ...
  post_shake:
    needs: [shake]
    steps:
      ...
```

Comment: `job.needs` [Identifies any jobs that must complete successfully before this job will run.](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) so it doesn't seem to be run if any of the shake shards fail...